# Default Timeout values for WCF Endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

Does anyone know the default values for the timeout of service endpoints in a WCF web service?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to MSDN the sendTimeout is 1 minute and the receiveTimeout is 10 minutes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx

Comment: And **1 min** for `openTimeout` and `closeTimeout`.